# How to save semi-structured data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how to persist a semi-structured document to MongoDB, using Spring Mongo. Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "admin": false,
  "unstructured_field_one": "Some arbitrary data"
}
```

I know how to do this with fully unstructured data as a field in a parent document, where I can just use something like

```
//...
private Object someRandomObject;
```

But how can I accomplish a semi-structured document (at parent level), where I have, as in the example, `name` and `admin` as required fields, and whatever else comes in along with the request gets added automagically?

Comment: `gets added automagically` where. You atleast need a field to store the values. You can ass a field like this `private Map<Object, Object> unstructuredData`

Comment: @pvpkiran, yes that I know - but that implies adding it under a separate field - which is exactly what I don't want to do. I want my structured (as in, the fields I catered for in my POJO) to be on the same level as the unstructured data. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without any pojo, just with a Json Parser(Jackson) and `MongoTemplate`. Since MongoTemplate can save any DbObject, You need to convert your json to a DBObject.
 Something like this will do

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> typeRef
        = new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() {};
 Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
 DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject(map);

 mongoTemplate.getCollection("blahblah").save(dbObject);
```